# Hold 2 selected item

Tags: jquery

I would like to add on my website a kind of selector with button like the picture. 
I already succeed with one button with the following code.
But I want to keep the first selection hold and select a second button. Sorry for my english I don't know if you understand me, I found this website which is actually doing exactly what I want.

Thank you in advance if you can help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BYxZ.jpg)

> 

```
$(function($){

  var $go = 'test1';
  var $notgo = 'test2';

  $('.romain-test-btn').each( function(){

  $(this).click( function(){

    $('.romain-test-retour').fadeIn();

    if (($(this).attr('id') == 1 ) || ($(this).attr('id') == 3 )){

     $('.romain-test-retour').html( $go );

        }else{


           $('.romain-test-retour').html( $notgo );

        }

    $('.romain-test-btn').fadeOut();




  });

  });

 });
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, an easy workaround would be to use some checkboxes and styled labels that look like buttons.

Comment: why did you choose to use javascript for this? i think with some simple html checkboxes and some good styling you can get the same result. and that would be easier to program. but if you do want this. maybe a foreach can help you out?: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

Comment: Thank you for your reply. do you have an example of html checkboxes wich stay selected. And when we select the second option a product suggestion appears ? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand exactly what you meant. But I think the problem is your query select `$('.romain-test-retour')`.
When you select by class name, all the elemets that has this class selected and function `html` apply on all that elements. You need to change your query select by id for example.

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="mybtn" id="btn1">btn1</button>
<button class="mybtn" id="btn2">btn2</button>
<button class="mybtn" id="btn3">btn3</button>
<button class="mybtn" id="btn4">btn4</button>
```

```
$(function($){

  $('.mybtn').click( function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('selected') || $('.selected').length <= 1)
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Actually I want to propose to my client a personalize experience. They could chose two options in order to find the right product for them. I offer them six options (buttons) and they must choose two. when they click on the first I would like it to remain selected and when they click on the second one a product proposal appears

Comment: you must select the button that user selected (not all the buttons) and add a class to show the button selected and with this class check the number of button that user clicked. in your code i can't see that.

Comment: Do you have an example for me ? sorry i'm pretty new in coding..